# How to get request.user in a code, which does not have any relation to views?

Tags: django

I want to get `user.pk` from `request` (for logged in user) in order to avoid additional DB queries.

In `views` there is incoming `request` variable. How to get this `request` somewhere else (not in views)? Directly importing `HttpRequest` does not help, because `HttpRequest` gets `user` object because of middleware modification. How can I get this 'modified' `HttpRequest` with `user` object? What do I need to import?

EDIT:
I want to implement customized user address, so user may have 2 types of addresses, like `mysite.com/username` or `mysite.com/id123`, so one link from navigation menu (`My page`) is dynamic. For the creation of navigation menu I use `django-sitetree`, where I want to do something like:

```
from sitetree.sitetreeapp import register_items_hook

def my_items_processor(tree_items, tree_sender):

    # get somehow `request`

    if tree_sender == 'menu.children':
        for item in tree_items:
            if request.user.username:
                item.url = request.user.username
            else:
                item.url = request.user.pk

    return tree_items
```

Comment: Is your function still in the request-response cycle, i.e. is there a current request that you just don't have access to in the current scope?

Comment: @knbk, I added new info above. As I understand, my function is out of request-response cycle. I need somehow to get the model of current logged in user. Usually I can get it from `request`. I tried to find any other way how to `get current user`, but no luck.

Comment: The concept of "currently logged in user" is directly tied to the request object. If this is outside the request-response cycle and no request exists, you can't access the logged in user because there isn't one. If it's in the request-response cycle you might be able to pass the request down to the function in some way, but if it isn't, then you're out of luck.

Comment: @knbk, thank you for the explanation. I will reorganize my code in order to put it in the request-responce cycle. If you want, you can make your comment as the answer and I accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I **just** answered this same question (albeit relating to `forms`) in another question. Please [see my answer there](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39193484/1036843).

Assuming you have setup `threadlocals.py` as detailed in that post, and stored it as `sitetree/threadlocals.py`:

```
from sitetree.sitetreeapp import register_items_hook
from sitetree.threadlocals import get_current_user

def my_items_processor(tree_items, tree_sender):

    user = get_current_user()

    if tree_sender == 'menu.children':
        for item in tree_items:
            if user.username:
                item.url = user.username
            else:
                item.url = user.pk

    return tree_items
```

Comment: Despite the answer is correct, I realized that the approach I wanted to use is not correct :) Better way as I currently see is to add a `user_url` field to my models.py and store there whether user_id or username

Comment: Good luck @TitanFighter!